# Few questions about Liang-Barsky Line Clipping Algorithm

Tags: geometry

(1) Is my conception correct that $t_{left}$ and $t_{bottom}$are always checked only against $t_{min}$, and, $t_{right}$ and $t_{top}$ are always checked only against $t_{max}$?

(2) How would the algorithm find the clipped line when PQ((340,160),(60,0)) and ClipRectangle((40,40),(280,200))?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I looked at LB clipping, but I don't believe that the first statement is correct. You can make it half-correct by swapping $P$ and $Q$ so that $P$ becomes the point whose $x$ coordinate is the smaller one, and keeping track of that at the end to re-orient the segment if needed, but I don't believe that LB actually does that. A better scheme might be to negate either all x-values or all y-values or both so that the segment "points northeast", and then do the same negations to the answer at the end of the algorithm, but I can't say that I recall LB doing that, either.

And now that I look in *Computer Graphics: Principles and Practice*, by Foley et al., I see that it's actually a little cleverer than that (although the description in the text doesn't cover this subtelty): the entire algorithm depends on $dx  = x_1 - x_0$ and $dy = y_1 - y_0$. The illustrations are drawn as if these were both positive, but then the algorithm does things like parametric clipping of $dx$ against $x_{min} - x_0$, which it refers to as "inside with respect to left edge", but the key thing to note is that the signs of $dx$ and $x_{min} - x_0$ might be opposite; even when they are, the parametric clipping still works (i.e., informally the sign of $dx$ effectively defines a "direction" in which to order the points $x_{min}$ and $x_{max}$).

As for #2, you're asking me to hand-simulate a 10-line algorithm for you, right? If there's some mathematics you don't understand, by all means ask, but I balk at the point where I'm asked to pretend to be an automaton. :)  Indeed, I fleshed out the answer to part 1 exactly by hand-simulating the answer to part 2 (OK, sorta hand-simulating it, very rapidly, in my head).

Finally, let me make a pitch for not studying this algorithm at all. In the modern world, clipping at the chip-level makes a lot more sense, and even traditional "scan conversion" is no longer relevant, because conversion to pixel-values is most often done by a slice-and-dice approach amenable to parallel processing rather than the sequential methods like Bresenham and midpoint, for which LB clipping is mostly a preparatory step. That why, in the new edition of *CGPP*, we left out Liang-Barsky and other clipping algorithms -- they're just not used a whole lot any more except in some minimal form by hardware rasterization algorithms.